# Getting unresolved reference

Tags: python

For some reason I am getting an unresolved reference 'i' error here in python 3.9.x

How can I amend my code to get it to run without error?

```
 for card in range(len(cards)):
    card = cards[i]
    print(f"{i+1} - {card}")

# get choice
choice = get_int_input(1, len(cards))
# get card
return cards[choice-1] if choice else None
```

'''

Comment: Take a look at your `for` loop. What is `i` _supposed_ to be? Where does it come from? Now take that `card = cards[i]` line out and see what happens. You are already creating `card` in your loop: `for card in...`. There's no need to index into `cards`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python is right. You has not `i` variable. Where do you see it?

If cards contains 4 element, your `card` will take successively `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`. So change your for loop like that:

```py
for i in range(len(cards)):
    card = cards[i]
    print(f"{i+1} - {card}")
```

But the best way to do what you want is like that:

```py
for i, card in enumerate(cards):
    print(f"{i+1} - {card}")
```

`enumerate` function will create an iterable variable that contains tuples of `(key, value)`. For example:

```py
>>> print(list(enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c'])))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

In the same example, this loop:

```py
for i, letter in enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

will take successively this variable:
| iterations | i | letter |
| ---- | ------ | ----- |
| 1 | 0 | 'a' |
| 2 | 1 | 'b' |
| 3 | 2 | 'c' |

Comment: More idiomatic would be `for i, card in enumerate(cards, start=1):`.

Comment: @chepner Yes, I was just adding it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to index your `card` value.

You need to adjust the first line of your loop as such:

```
for i in range(len(cards)):
    card = cards[i]
    print(f"{i+1} - {card}")
```

but this is not the most pythonic way. Instead what you can do is just call cards directly, and use enumerate if you need the index.

```
for index, card in enumerate(cards):
    print(f"{index+1} - {card}")
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing the for loop to:

for i in range(len(cards)):